# CSS allowing element to disappear but not reappear on check event

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get my CSS to affect the second element after a check box.  In my example, I have a Font Awesome symbol displaying on unchecked and a different one when checked. Currently the icons hide and the unchecked one displays but the checked icon does not. See below code or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Chunk/318tu05a/).

I have tried using the adjacent rule (+) with `input:checked + n + y` and the contains rule (~) with `input:checked ~ n + y` and even nth-child variations with no luck. IMO if I can get the element to disappear with CSS them I should be able to make it reappear, I hope I haven't been tearing my hair out for something simple. I'm aware of other questions on SO and even trying the workaround of `input:checked + n + y {}` did not appear to help either.

P.S. I'm afraid a Javascript alternative will not be of help to me.

```css
.container {
}
.container > label {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.container > label > input {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.container > label > span {
    display: inline-block;
}
.container > label > input + n {
    color: #C77AA6;
}
.container > label > input:checked + n {
    display: none;
}
.container > label > input + n + y {
    display: none;
}
.container > label > input:checked + n + y {
    color: #C77AA6;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="radioGroup" />
        <n class="fa fa-square-o fa-1x"></n>
        <y class="fa fa-check-square-o fa-1x"></y>
        Item 1
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="radioGroup" />
        <n class="fa fa-square-o fa-1x"></n>
        <y class="fa fa-check-square-o fa-1x"></y>
        Item 2
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="radioGroup" />
        <n class="fa fa-square-o fa-1x"></n>
        <y class="fa fa-check-square-o fa-1x"></y>
        Item 2a
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="radioGroup" />
        <n class="fa fa-square-o fa-1x"></n>
        <y class="fa fa-check-square-o fa-1x"></y>
        Item 3
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selectors look fine, you might just missing this:

```
.container > label > input:checked + n + y {
    color: #C77AA6;
    display: inline-block; /*add this*/
}
```

Side note, `radio` and `checkbox` function differently, they must not look the same. I fixed that by using `fa-circle-o` and `fa-dot-circle-o` for the radio icons.

```css
.container {
}
.container > label {
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.container > label > input {
    visibility: hidden;
}
.container > label > span {
    display: inline-block;
}
.container > label > input + n {
    color: #C77AA6;
}
.container > label > input:checked + n {
    display: none;
}
.container > label > input + n + y {
    display: none;
}
.container > label > input:checked + n + y {
    color: #C77AA6;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="radioGroup" />
        <n class="fa fa-circle-o fa-1x"></n>
        <y class="fa fa-dot-circle-o fa-1x"></y>
        Item 1
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="radio" name="radioGroup" />
        <n class="fa fa-circle-o fa-1x"></n>
        <y class="fa fa-dot-circle-o fa-1x"></y>
        Item 2
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="radioGroup" />
        <n class="fa fa-square-o fa-1x"></n>
        <y class="fa fa-check-square-o fa-1x"></y>
        Item 2a
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="radioGroup" />
        <n class="fa fa-square-o fa-1x"></n>
        <y class="fa fa-check-square-o fa-1x"></y>
        Item 3
    </label>
</div>
```